# Strange Sign on Lab Door

Tags: lab-management

I saw a strange sign on a door to a geophysics lab in a museum in Switzerland. I was really curious about what it means and wanted to know if anyone is familiar with this sign.

[image]

Here's the full image of the door so you can see the context/type of work going on in the lab.

[image]

Comment: I'm also curious about what the two signs to the right of the one you indicated mean. (I'm guessing the one you indicated is a joke, but I could be wrong or partially missing the joke)

Comment: Somebody doesn’t like Mrs. Tiggy-Winkle I guess...

Comment: @cag51 I'm pretty sure they're warnings against pacemakers and joint replacements, due to the strong magnetic fields.

Comment: @cag51 The heart is no pace makers and the middle one is no medical implants.

Comment: I thought the middle one was depicting a hearing aid inside an ear canal, but upon further inspection it does appear to be a hip joint.

Comment: If you're there to take a picture, why can't you just ask them?

Comment: Middle and right are related to magnetic field. Prosthetic implants and pace mskers respectively, as jakebeal said.

Comment: How about the topmost sign? "Caution! Cocktail shaker in use?"

Comment: ...Nope! It apparently means, "Danger! High-pressure gas bottles are stored/used in here." Thanks, TinEye!

Comment: Are really *all* implants forbidden in NMR labs? I've had two medical MRI scans and I have a titanium implant afer a fracture.

Comment: @VladimirF: There are always 2 distinct considerations: whether the magnetic field (and your moving in that field) can cause harm to you, and whether the implant disturbs the magnetic field and causes artifacts. Ti isn't as bad as ferromagnetic materials, but for medical MRI it may still mean that while harmless to you the whole MRI is pointless due to artifacts => AFAIK implants in MRI are pretty much decided case-to-case. For technical MRI/MRS labs it's just easier to have someone without implant do the work inside the magnetic field.

Comment: I think the middle one is a clown. No clowns!

Answer (score 85):

I notice that the sign:

- Doesn't quite match the other signs for scale or style
- Isn't obvious in what it's communicating (unlike normal warning signs)
- Looks like a monster (apparently "We Must All Stop [ManBearPig](https://www.amazon.ca/CafePress-Stop-ManBearPig-Sticker-Bumper/dp/B00FOMU7N4)" from South Park):
          [image].

I conclude that it's a joke by the museum staff, much like this "[velociraptor-free workplace](https://peripatetic-life.blogspot.com/2017/01/velociraptor-safety-field-museum-chicago.html)" sign at the Field Museum in Chicago.

Comment: I didn't know what is the concept behind this? it seems scary and I don't think it is a joke and if joke what does it mean? Is that  customary logo at geology?

Comment: @Monkia: [ManBearPig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ManBearPig) is from the American animated comedy TV show [South Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park).  It's clearly a joke.  Probably someone who works in the lab is a fan of the show.  It could be a joke with some deeper meaning, since the ManBearPig character was meant as an allegory for climate change, but it's hard to guess what exactly the person who put up the sign might have had in mind.  It certainly isn't anything that's generally "customary" in geology or any other academic field.

Comment: @Monkia you won’t necessarily get the joke as it may be “lab” specific ie if most if the lab workers watch that show they may have had a conversation or several about it and that is an “in-house” reference to a particular episode or character for a reason **they** find funny or memorable. Outsiders won’t get it.

Answer (score 36):

***tl;dr*-**  It's [ManBearPig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ManBearPig) from [*South Park*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park).  In the future, you can look up stuff like this with a [reverse image search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_image_search), like [this one](https://www.tineye.com/search/3d9e0956af00af27cf41859cf3e593d5b1641825/).

---

If you find a strange indicator on a lab door, it may be easiest to do a [reverse image search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_image_search).  It's sorta like Google'ing something, just you're querying with an image rather than words.

In this case, I tried [TinEye](https://www.tineye.com/), searching with the image you provided in the question,
             [image],
by referring to its URL, `https://i.stack.imgur.com/usUNw.png`.  The [search results page](https://www.tineye.com/search/3d9e0956af00af27cf41859cf3e593d5b1641825/) reveals that this is a warning about the infamous [ManBearPig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ManBearPig), as previously documented in the series [*South Park*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park).

Obviously, this serves as not just a warning about the horrors of the existing monster, but to remind researchers about the potential hazards of their reckless tinkering in what man was not meant to meddle with.

Comment: It doesn't work for [the strange sign on my lab door](https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/398_10200702207178160_975719176_n.jpg?_nc_cat=108&_nc_ht=scontent-lhr3-1.xx&oh=ffb28e79c6b1518b4b45d601e59856dc&oe=5D19F85A) (though that's a little more self-explanatory in a metric lab)

Comment: @ChrisH. Facebook tends to move assets around, so that link is now dead.

Comment: @TRiG they've essentially prevented external sharing of photos for some time now. Mine read "absolutely no imperial hardware allowed" with  a forbidden symbol banning Star Wars Imperial machines